# Redirect to another site from WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, redirect, asp.net-web-api

The case in hand is as follows:

1. User hits a control on a website, website calls an API.
2. API does some logic, and shall then construct a post http request and redirect to another site.
3. User should view the redirected site.

Alternative solution i guess is for the api to return an object that the website can use to redirect.

Your kind suggestions and ideas

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [HTTP/1.1 Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3). Specifically section 10.3 "Redirection 3xx". It describes the available status codes, and you should be able to find a suitable one.

**Example: 303 See Other**

Your API would create a response with status code 303 and add a "Location" header that contains the address of the site you redirect to.

Comment: I agree.  WebAPI should be used as a model in most architectures, so very little logic in the program flow should come from the api itself.  returning a 303 and letting the front end handle redirecting to the appropriate place is the right call.

Comment: Whilst you could return some kind of redirect http status code from the web api controller I don't think it makes a lot of sense to do this.  The web api response should relate to the ajax post you have just made, you are not telling the client that it should redirect it's post elsewhere, the web api controller should return 200 indicating the post was successful.